# Why is there a double quote at the beginning of the my result?

Tags: javascript

I have tried looking for this problem here but still can't find an answer (maybe I'm too newbie to even write the exact keywords).
I am trying to overcome freecodecamp challenge on "binary agent", my question is not "How to convert binary to text string" But

why is there a double quote at the beginning of the my result ?

Thank You

```js
function binaryAgent(str) {
  let binaryArr;
  let decimalArr = [];
  let textArr = [];
  let joinTextArr;
  for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    // convert binary to decimal use parseInt(value, radix)
    binaryArr = str.split(" ");
    decimalArr.push(parseInt(binaryArr[i], 2));
    decimalArr = decimalArr.filter( value => !Number.isNaN(value) );
    // convert decimal to text
    textArr.push(String.fromCharCode(decimalArr[i]))
    // join to be a string
    joinTextArr = textArr.join("")
  }
  return joinTextArr;
}

console.log(binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111"));

// result > "Aren't bonfires fun!?
```

Comment: Have you tried to re-check the result again? It doesn't output any double quote on my machine.

Comment: Are you running this code at freecodecamp? Maybe their `console.log` implementation prints strings with quotes and escaping.

Comment: I running at mozilla site code panel here "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt"
and I tried running it on freecodecamp too but for some reason it didn't pass the challenge, that's why I think the double quote is the cause..

Comment: @Bergi I have tried but still didn't pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

All Javascript strings will have double quotes at the beginning when printed. Hence, the problem isn't that there is a double quote printed at the start of your console log output. Rather, the issue is that there *isn't* a double quote printed at the end of your logged string. In fact, the end double quote is indeed printed at the end of your logged string, but is prefixed by a long string of undefined characters, which might explain why you might have missed it:

[image]

The underlying issue is because you are iterating through the individual characters of the string in

```
for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++)
```

This results in your index `i` going out of bounds of `binaryArr`. Thus, `textArr` is appended with undefined variables, leading to the actual string being printed as the final `textArr` to be (note the ending trail of undefined characters)

```
["A", "r", "e", "n", "'", "t", " ", "b", "o", "n", "f", "i", "r", "e", "s", " ", "f", "u", "n", "!", "?", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

### Fix

Rather, you want to split the input string into the individual binary words before iterating through in your for loop.

```
  function binaryAgent(str) {
    let binaryArr = str.split(" ");
    let decimalArr = [];
    let textArr = [];
    let joinTextArr;
    for (let i=0; i<binaryArr.length; i++){
      // convert binary to decimal use parseInt(value, radix)
      decimalArr.push(parseInt(binaryArr[i], 2));
      decimalArr = decimalArr.filter( value => !Number.isNaN(value) );
      // convert decimal to text
      textArr.push(String.fromCharCode(decimalArr[i]))
      // join to be a string
    }
    joinTextArr = textArr.join("")

    return joinTextArr
}
```

Also, I included a small optimization that only calculates `joinTextArr` at the end of the loop, since that only has to be done once.

Comment: I think I now understand the problem, so line `decimalArr = decimalArr.filter( value => !Number.isNaN(value) )`  is no longer needed

Comment: That's right! If the input string is formatted correctly